# Running AngularJS Protractor with IE11

Tags: angularjs, node.js, internet-explorer, selenium, protractor

I am having trouble running AngularJS Protractor through Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7.  It works fine if I use Google Chrome, but with IE11, I get the following error message:

> WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property: for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Within the protractor directory is a sub-directory called ***selenium***, and there is an ***IEDriverServer file***.  Furthermore, I have two environment variables set.  In my user variables, the variable **PATH** has a value of `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\`

Additionally, in my system variables, the variable "**Path**" is also set to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\`, but it will still not recognize the IE driver server, even though it DOES recognize the Chrome driver server.

Does anyone have any additional information on what I might be missing or doing wrong?  Thank you very much.